# Alternative XSLT processor to Apache Xalan

Tags: xslt, saxon, xalan, libxslt

I am currently using the Apache Xalan XSLT processor in my Java application, but I would like to use some alternative solution which supports use of extension functions. Xalan seems to be out of date and buggy. I know of Saxonixa Saxon, but it is closed sourced. Is there some open source and well working alternative?

Comment: Saxon 9 HE is up to date, open-source and supports both XSLT based, user-defined functions with `xsl:function` as well as extension functions in Java (if you use the approach of "integrated extension functions" documented in http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensibility/integratedfunctions/).

Comment: AFAIK, Xalan supports calls to Java.

Answer (score 3):

The current open source version of Saxon, Saxon-HE 9.9, supports "integrated extension functions" (functions written to a particular Saxon-defined Java interface). It doesn't support "reflexive" extension functions (calls to arbitrary Java classes/methods found on the classpath).

Note that if you move to Saxon, with support for XSLT 2.0 and 3.0, you will find there is much less need for calling out to Java, because (a) the built-in function library is much larger, and (b) you can implement your own functions using the `xsl:function` declaration.