# java external function call saxon 9.9he xslt

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

we are using **xalan** for xml transformation. now we are migrating to **saxon 9.9 HE** for xslt 3.0 support and improved performance.

**Current code**

**Java code**

```
  HashMap<String, String> columnPropsMap= getProperties(strDSNName);

  transformer.setParameter("propsMap", columnPropsMap);//set map to xslt

 **XSLT**
 ...xmlns:map="xalan://java.util.Map" extension-element-prefixes="map"
 ...<xsl:param name="propsMap"/> <!--read map passed from java-->
 ...<xsl:variable name="defaultvalue"  select="map:get($propsMap,translate($udpname,$lowercase,$uppercase))"/><!-- retrieve the property for udp(property) by udpname from  hashmap propsMap-->



    **New code**

  **java**
  System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
             "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");//set saxon transformer factory

  **XSLT**

  xmlns:map="http://ns.saxonica.com/map" extension-element-prefixes="map"<!--namespace change-->
```

i am getting below error for line involving map:get($propsMap,translate($udpname,$lowercase,$uppercase)). i believe 9.9 HE doesnt not support external call functions. alternatively we need to use custom functions using ExtensionFunctionDefinition. not able to figure out how to do the same for reading a map and setting value

Request to suggest how handle map params in xslt  in SAxon 9.9 HE

**Error stack trace**

```
Error evaluating ((element()[fn:name(...) eq "UDP_Instance_Groups"])/element()[fn:name(...) eq "UDP_Instance"]!let $udpval := ...) in xsl:variable/@select on line 953 column 113 
  XTDE1425: Cannot find a 2-argument function named Q{http://ns.saxonica.com/map}get()
     invoked by unknown caller (class net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ForEach) at #947
     invoked by unknown caller (class net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ForEach) at #568
  In template rule with match="*[fn:name(...) eq "Physical_Columns_Order_Ref"]" on line 565 of 
     invoked by xsl:apply-templates at #509
     invoked by unknown caller (class net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ForEach) at #81
  In template rule with match="/" on line 38 of 
   ; SystemID: ; Line#: 953; Column#: 60
  net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Cannot find a 2-argument function named   Q{http://ns.saxonica.com/map}get()
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.ErrorExpression.evaluateItem(ErrorExpression.java:149)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.Evaluator$5.evaluate(Evaluator.java:191)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.Evaluator$5.evaluate(Evaluator.java:188)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.eval(LetExpression.java:532)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.process(LetExpression.java:601)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ForEach.lambda$processLeavingTail$0(ForEach.java:484)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ForEach$$Lambda$51/1933790033.accept(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceIterator.forEachOrFail(SequenceIterator.java:128)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ForEach.processLeavingTail(ForEach.java:484)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:132)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:352)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:299)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:735)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(LetExpression.java:723)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:735)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(LetExpression.java:723)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:735)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(LetExpression.java:723)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:735)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(LetExpression.java:723)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:735)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:132)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:352)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:299)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(LetExpression.java:723)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Choose.processLeavingTail(Choose.java:896)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Choose.processLeavingTail(Choose.java:896)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:132)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ForEach.lambda$processLeavingTail$0(ForEach.java:484)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ForEach$$Lambda$51/1933790033.accept(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceIterator.forEachOrFail(SequenceIterator.java:128)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ForEach.processLeavingTail(ForEach.java:484)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(LetExpression.java:723)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.TemplateRule.applyLeavingTail(TemplateRule.java:352)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:533)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ApplyTemplates.apply(ApplyTemplates.java:300)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ApplyTemplates.process(ApplyTemplates.java:251)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:352)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:299)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:735)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(LetExpression.java:723)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:735)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:132)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:352)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:299)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Choose.processLeavingTail(Choose.java:896)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:132)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ForEach.lambda$processLeavingTail$0(ForEach.java:484)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ForEach$$Lambda$51/1933790033.accept(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceIterator.forEachOrFail(SequenceIterator.java:128)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ForEach.processLeavingTail(ForEach.java:484)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:132)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:352)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:299)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:735)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:132)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:352)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:299)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:735)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:132)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:352)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:299)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:735)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:132)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:352)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:299)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(LetExpression.java:723)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.TemplateRule.applyLeavingTail(TemplateRule.java:352)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:533)
```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56770499/alternative-xslt-processor-to-apache-xalan/56771277#56771277) you have de general answer and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57423698/iterate-arraylist-returned-by-java-extension-function-in-xsltsaxon/57427483#57427483) you have an example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate ArrayList returned by Java extension function in XSLT(Saxon)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57423698/iterate-arraylist-returned-by-java-extension-function-in-xsltsaxon)

Comment: Consider to use an  XPATH 3.1 map on the XSLT side

Comment: Please note also, the namespace `http://ns.saxonica.com/map` was used for an experimental Saxon implementation of maps while the XSLT 3.0 specification was still in an early draft stage; it appeared around Saxon 9.3 or 9.4, and has long since been superseded by the official XSLT 3.0 version.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use an XDM 3.1 map (i.e. sequence type `map(xs:string, xs:string)`) on the XSLT side for the parameter, then you can simply use the XPath 3.1 map access features (e.g. `$map($key)`, `$map?key`) and XPath 3.1 map functions https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#map-functions.

To convert your java.util.Map to an XDM map when you pass in the parameter use the method `makeMap` (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XdmMap.html#makeMap-java.util.Map-).